# how to transfer files and folders from windows (host) to linux (virtual machine)

Tags: virtualbox

Please I wish to transfer files and folders from Windows (host) to Linux (virtual machine) using WinSCP.
Any ideas?

Comment: http://winscp.net/eng/docs/start

Comment: Please **do your homework first**! http://serverfault.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: WinSCP makes it so incredibly easy and obvious I simply don't believe that you are unable to do it.

Answer (score 3):

It's as simple as running SSHD on the Linux VM and using WinSCP to connect to it over an IP network. Nothing special. Just make sure you have a properly functioning virtual network.

A better option to transfer files to a guest would be to use [VirtualBox Shared Folders](http://virtuatopia.com/index.php/VirtualBox_Shared_Folders).

Comment: +1 for Vbox shared folders.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers I've been here three years and it's only been in the last six months or so that I consistently check the tags. Even then, it's only because I know people leave out vital information until they're forced to tag the post before submitting it. =) Anyway... let the comment deletion begin...